# How to displaying Custom image, text and default image logo from Redux Framework option panel

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I am using Redux framework option panel to handle logo on my header.

The scenario:

1. Display custom logo when I upload my own logo.
2. Display text logo when the custom logo not active.
3. Display default logo when custom logo and text logo not active.

My code here:

```
 <?php global $redux_demo; if ( isset($redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']) ){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"> <img alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" src="
<?php if( isset($redux_demo['opt_header_logo']) ){ ?>
<?php echo esc_url($redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']); ?>
<?php } ?>"> </a>
<?php } 

else if ( isset($redux_demo['opt_header_logo']) ){ ?>
<h1> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<?php if( isset($redux_demo['opt_header_text']) ){ ?>
<?php echo esc_html($redux_demo['opt_header_text']); ?>
<?php } ?>
</a> </h1>
<?php }

else { ?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png' ); ?>">
<?php } 
 ?>
```

These code only work for custom logo and default logo (scenario 1 and 3.) But did not work when I want to use text as logo.
Really appreciate for any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <?php 

 global $redux_demo; 
 if ( isset($redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']) && !empty($redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']) ){ 
 ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"> <img alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" src="<?php echo esc_url($redux_demo['opt_header_logo']['url']); ?>"> </a>
<?php } else if ( isset($redux_demo['opt_header_text']) && !empty($redux_demo['opt_header_text']) ){ ?>
<h1> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<?php echo esc_html($redux_demo['opt_header_text']); ?>
</a> </h1>
<?php }else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png' ); ?>"></a>
<?php } ?>
```